# How can I play simulteanously two different audio using headphones for one and internal speakers for the other?

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

How can I play audio through both speakers and headphones in Ubuntu 14 LTS? I want to use mixxx to play deck 1 through speakers and deck 2 in headphones.  TIA

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use a USB headphone (or a $5 USB audio device to plug your headphone) , and to select this USB sound device for deck2 in Mixxx sound preferences.

---

Another way  depends on your sound card:
There is a possibility to create a new audio device just by activating "independent HP" in Alsamixer.

First, run `alsamixer` in a maximized terminal  and search if you have a fader called *independent* (the name is under the fader, see screen capture at the end).
(Sometimes if you see only one fader you have to press <kbd>F6</kbd> and select your main sound card if it is not the default.)
If no *independent* fader, no chance.
Else, follow the following steps after disconnecting you headphone jack and closing all audio software 
(close also the previous `alsamixer` pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> in its terminal):

1. Stop  pulseaudio copying and running successively these 3 commands in a terminal:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.pulse
   echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf
   pulseaudio -k
   ```
2. Relaunch `alsamixer` in a terminal, use left/right arrows keys to move to the *independent* fader, change its state to *enabled*
   using up arrow key.

   Also verify *speaker* and *headphones* fader are not muted (`MM` under the fader means "muted", `00` is ok.)

   Now, as in *independent* mode, a  new audio output is created for headphone only (called `hw:0,2`), in addition to the default device  (`hw:0,0`) which is for speaker.
3. Go to the Mixxx sound preferences and select `soundcard_name (hw:0,0)` for deck1, `soundcard_name (hw:2,0)` for deck2, "none" for main and headphones.
4. Later, you can revert to pulseaudio running

   ```
   echo autospawn=yes > ~/.pulse/client.conf
   pulseaudio -D
   ```

<sup>([source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio-Controls.txt))</sup>

[image: mixxx]
[image: alsamixer]