# Can send Pidgin sound to laptop speakers when headphones are plugged in?

Tags: sound, headphones, pidgin

Is it possible to control sound output per application?

I'd like to set things up so that when my headphones are plugged in, most sound goes to the headphones (e.g. music), but sound from Pidgin (e.g. ping on new message) goes to the laptop speakers?

(An acceptable alternative would be to direct sound from the music player to the headphones, and all other sound to the laptop speakers.)

Comment: It can be done at Alsa level , see this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/534777/how-can-i-play-simulteanously-two-different-audio-using-headphones-for-one-and-i/535956#535956